# Questions & Answer - User Input not accepted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a question and answer website where the user inputs a question, I take the users input and compare it against the database, If the answer is correct, I take the value of the question and add it to the scoreboard, However I am having an issue where the users input is not being passed through the models, and when I set the `@user_input = params[:content]`, It is always returning null, I believe this is because I am using namespace/nested models.

**The plan of actions:**

```
Get the current answer from the database for the current_question_id, and set as a varaiable

Check Users input against the answer in the database
    if question_id & user_submitted_answer exists in database
        create record in submission's table with status == correct
    else
        create record in submissions table with status  == Incorrect
```

Models:

**members/question**

```
class Members::Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :point
  belongs_to :event

  has_many :submissions
  has_one :answer
end
```

**Submissions**

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
    belongs_to :member
end
```

**Routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  #Root Routes
  root 'home#index'  
  get 'home/index'
  get 'home/about'  

  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/eriadmin', as: 'rails_admin'

  #Devise Controller
  devise_for :members

  #Members namepsace
  get '/members/', to: 'members/dashboard#index', as: 'members_dashboard',  only: [:show]

  resources :answers

  namespace :members do
    resources :questions,  only: [:index,:show] do
      resources :submissions 
    end
  end
end
```

**Submissions Controller 
Create Method**

```
@answer_check = Answer.where("question_id = ? AND content = ?",set_members_question,  set_user_submission)
    if @answer_check.present?

        flash.alert = 'Answer There'
        @submission = @members_question.submissions.create(params[:submission].permit(:question_id))
        @submission.member_id =  current_member.id

        @submission.content = Submission.find_by(params[:content])


    else
        flash.alert = 'NOPE NOT There'
        @submission = @members_question.submissions.create(params[:submission].permit(:question_id))
        @submission.content = "Incorrect"
        @submission.member_id =  current_member.id
    end

def set_user_submission
  @members_question =  Submission.find(params[:content])
end
```

The user_submitted_answer :content is not being passed from the form in the "Questions/Show" into the submissions controller?

Am I doing this wrong, approaching it wrong or is there a rails method that I can use that is more efficient and works to achieve what I need?

My current code, Always returns false and the users_input is not being inserted into the database.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you are creating the submission in either of the cases, then assigning the content and member id and not saving it.

Keep in mind that create method initializes the object and also saves it after which any values you assign needs to be saved again. So I have tweaked your code as follows where the submission object is initialized then you add the content and member_id and atlast you save it.

```
if @answer_check.present?
    flash.alert = 'Answer There'
    @submission = @members_question.submissions.new(params[:submission].permit(:question_id))
    @submission.member_id =  current_member.id

    @submission.content = Submission.find_by(params[:content])
    @submission.save
else
    flash.alert = 'NOPE NOT There'
    @submission = @members_question.submissions.new(params[:submission].permit(:question_id))
    @submission.content = "Incorrect"
    @submission.member_id =  current_member.id
    @submission.save
end
```

Hope this works and please upvote if deemed correct!

Cheers!

Comment: I have upvoted your question so that you have enough points to upvote answers!

Comment: Will be attempting this in a few minutes, will let you know if it works.

Comment: Sure! Let me know!